# Positioning forms and multiple images

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, centering

I'm having issues centering a form vertically and horizontally, I've managed to horizontally center the form, but cant manage to also center it vertically without causing the form and the images overlap. Also having issues horizontally centering multiple images at the bottom of the page.

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #595959;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#imagesMain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 75rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#imagesMain a {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1.5%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#form {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <div class="banner">
    <h1>A-Level Revision Website</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="form">
    <form id="loginForm">
      <input type="email" class="login-username" autofocus="true" required="true" placeholder="Email" /><br>
      <input type="password" class="login-password" required="true" placeholder="Password" /><br>
      <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" class="login-submit" /><br>
      <a href="#" class="login-forgot-pass">forgot password?</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="imagesMain">
    <a href="Maths.html">
   <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/9a/c8/069ac81cbe0e3a6f8fb43a0df42125a0.jpg" alt="Maths"">
  </a>
    <a href="ComputerScience.html">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/9a/c8/069ac81cbe0e3a6f8fb43a0df42125a0.jpg" alt="ComputerScience">
    </a>
    <a href="Physics.html">  
   <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/9a/c8/069ac81cbe0e3a6f8fb43a0df42125a0.jpg" alt="Physics"">
  </a>
  </div>

  </html>
```

Comment: centering the login form both vertically and horizontally in the center of the whole page, and the images centered horizontally at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}
body, html {height: 100%}

#container {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks them vertically */
  height: 100%;
}

.banner,
#loginForm,
.images {
  flex: 1;
}

/* Another example:
.banner {flex: 1}
#loginForm {flex: 2} Means that it takes twice as much space as .banner and .images (100% / 4 (in flex values) = 25%, i.e. flex: 1 = 25%).
.images {flex: 1}
*/

.banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* centers them horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* centers them vertically */
  text-align: center;
  background: #595959;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#loginForm {
  display: flex; /* also given flex properties */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks the login form elements vertically */
  justify-content: center; /* aligns the form horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* aligns the form vertically */
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#loginForm > input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.images {
  display: flex; /* also given flex properties */
  justify-content: center; /* aligns images horizontally */
  align-items: flex-end; /* aligns images at the bottom */
  padding: 10px 5px; /* for better presentation */
  background: #595959; /* for better presentation */
}

.images > a {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.images > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="banner">
    <h1>A-Level Revision Website</h1>
  </div>
  <form id="loginForm">
    <input type="email" class="login-username" placeholder="E-mail" autofocus="true" required>
    <input type="password" class="login-password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit" class="login-submit" name="Login" value="Login">
    <a href="#" class="login-forgot-pass">Forgot password?</a>
  </form>
  <div class="images">
    <a href="Maths.html"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/9a/c8/069ac81cbe0e3a6f8fb43a0df42125a0.jpg" alt="Maths"></a>
    <a href="ComputerScience.html"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/9a/c8/069ac81cbe0e3a6f8fb43a0df42125a0.jpg" alt="ComputerScience"></a>
    <a href="Physics.html"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/9a/c8/069ac81cbe0e3a6f8fb43a0df42125a0.jpg" alt="Physics"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This solution is fully responsive. I gave all three *children* the `flex` *value* of `1` to make them equal in `height` (100% / 3 (in `flex` values) = *33.33%*, i.e. `flex: 1` = *33.33%*).
If you want you can give each child a different value, e.g. `#container > .banner {flex: 1;}` `#container > #loginForm {flex: 2;}` `#container > .images {flex: 3;}` or any other number (can also use decimals) and see how they respond.

You can adjust `flex` *values* to your needs to get the desired result, but please note that different values for `.banner` and `.images` result in `#loginForm` not being *vertically centered* on the screen. Also note that if the original `height` of the content (`img`s) inside the *flex-item* is, at some point, bigger than the `height` of the *item* itself, then that will affect the *flex-items* `height`.